# Let vs set syntax in vimrc

Tags: vimrc

I can do the following to set the `synmtaxcol`:

```
:set synmaxcol=4
```

Or:

```
:let &synmaxcol=4
```

However, when doing the same with `colorscheme`, only this works:

```
colorscheme TextMate
```

And not:

```
let &colorscheme="TextMate"
```

Or:

```
let g:colors_name="TextMate"
```

When is the `let` syntax available to use / how would I update the colors with a `let` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `let` can be used with vimscript variables, registers, environment variables and options. As colorscheme is not one of those (it’s a different mechanism—it involves sourcing a file, which itself must give `g:colors_name` the appropriate value), it cannot be set this way.

To use options, the `&` syntax a few variants are helpful. Why? Often we want to save and restore options:

```
let save_cpo = &cpo
let &cpo = save_cpo
```

Or we want to set an option more programmatically:

```
let &path = some_fancy_expression
```

The latter in particular is easier to read and deal with than `:execute "set path=".some_fancy_expression`.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to set the colorscheme via running a `let` command?

Comment: Not as far as i know—you can use `execute "colorscheme" expression` though